# React Material UI Datepicker without timezone

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to develop a React material ui datepicker. It "post" with timezone in the mysql Database:
2020-08-16T20:06:09.344Z

the format should like this:
16.08.2020

How I can change the String Format in React frontend or in the Java Backend?
In Java and in mysql the date is a String.

```js
export default function Speisereste() {

  const classes = useStyles();
  const [firstLoad, setLoad] = React.useState(true);

  const [datum, setDatum] = React.useState(new Date());

  const handleDatumChange = (date) => {
    setDatum(date);
  };

  console.log(datum);
  const [message, setMessage] = React.useState("Nothing saved in the session");

  async function sampleFunc(toInput) {
    const response = await fetch("/speisereste", {
      method: "POST", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
      mode: "cors", // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
      cache: "no-cache", // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
      credentials: "same-origin", // include, *same-origin, omit
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
        // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      redirect: "follow", // manual, *follow, error
      referrerPolicy: "no-referrer", // no-referrer, *client
      body: JSON.stringify(toInput) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
    });
    let body = await response.json();
    console.log(body.id);
    setMessage(body.id ? "Data sucessfully updated" : "Data updating failed");
  }

  const handleSubmit = variables => {
    const toInput = { datum };
    sampleFunc(toInput);
    setDatum(datum);
  };


  if (firstLoad) {
    //  sampleFunc();
    setLoad(false);
  }


  return (
  
   <FormControl required className={classes.formControl}>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                  <DatePicker
                    label="Datum"
                    value={datum}
                    format="dd/MM/yyyy"
                    onChange={handleDatumChange}
                    animateYearScrolling
                  />
                </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
              </Grid>
            </FormControl>
          </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript Date object :

```
var d = new Date('2020-08-16T20:06:09.344Z');
console.log(d.getUTCHours()); // Hours
console.log(d.getUTCMinutes());
console.log(d.getUTCSeconds());
```

Or use momentjs : http://momentjs.com/

```
var localTime = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'); // store localTime
var proposedDate = localTime + "T00:00:00.000Z";
```

now that you have the right format for a time, parse it if it's valid:

```
var isValidDate = moment(proposedDate).isValid();
// returns true if valid and false if it is not.
```

and to get time parts you can do something like:

```
var momentDate = moment(proposedDate)
var hour = momentDate.hours();
var minutes = momentDate.minutes();
var seconds = momentDate.seconds();

// or you can use `.format`:
console.log(momentDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss A Z"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it's not working. I only want the date not the time when I post to the database,

```js
export default function Speisereste() {

  var d = new Date('dd/MM/yyyy');

  const classes = useStyles();
  const [firstLoad, setLoad] = React.useState(true);

  const [speisen, setSpeisen] = React.useState("");
  const [department, setDepartment] = React.useState("");
  const [gewicht, setGewicht] = React.useState("");
  const [grund, setGrund] = React.useState("");
  const [datum, setDatum] = React.useState(d);

  const handleDatumChange = (date) => {
    setDatum(date);
  };

  console.log(datum);


  const handleSpeisenChange = event => setSpeisen(event.target.value);
  const handleDepartmentChange = event => setDepartment(event.target.value);
  const handleGewichtChange = event => setGewicht(event.target.value);
  const handleGrundChange = event => setGrund(event.target.value);

  const [message, setMessage] = React.useState("Nothing saved in the session");

  async function sampleFunc(toInput) {
    const response = await fetch("/speisereste", {
      method: "POST", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
      mode: "cors", // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
      cache: "no-cache", // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
      credentials: "same-origin", // include, *same-origin, omit
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
        // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      redirect: "follow", // manual, *follow, error
      referrerPolicy: "no-referrer", // no-referrer, *client
      body: JSON.stringify(toInput) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
    });
    let body = await response.json();
    console.log(body.id);
    setMessage(body.id ? "Data sucessfully updated" : "Data updating failed");
  }

  const handleSubmit = variables => {
    const toInput = { speisen, department, gewicht, grund, datum };
    sampleFunc(toInput);
    setSpeisen("");
    setDepartment("");
    setGewicht("");
    setGrund("");
    setDatum(datum);
    
  };


  if (firstLoad) {
    //  sampleFunc();
    setLoad(false);
  }


  return (

    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <div className="logo">
          <img src={logo} width="300" height="100" />
        </div>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Speisereste Analyse App
        </Typography>

        <FormControl required className={classes.form}>
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="speisen"
                value={speisen}
                label="Beilage, Gemüse, Salat"
                name="speisen"
                autoComplete="speisen"
                onChange={handleSpeisenChange}
              />
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <FormControl required className={classes.formControl}>
                <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-required-label">Gewicht</InputLabel>
                <Select
                  labelId="demo-customized-select-label"
                  id="demo-customized-select"
                  value={gewicht}
                  onChange={handleGewichtChange}
                >
                  <MenuItem value={0.5}>0.5kg</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value={1.0}>1.0kg</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value={1.5}>1.5kg</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value={2.0}>2.0kg</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value={2.5}>2.5kg</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value={3.0}>3.0kg</MenuItem>
                </Select>
              </FormControl>
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <FormControl required className={classes.formControl}>
                <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-required-label">Niederlassung</InputLabel>
                <Select
                  labelId="demo-customized-select-label"
                  id="demo-customized-select"
                  value={department}
                  onChange={handleDepartmentChange}
                >
                  <MenuItem value={9043}>AWKG</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value={9032}>SWG</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value={9033}>WIS</MenuItem>
                </Select>
              </FormControl>
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <FormControl required className={classes.formControl}>
                <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-required-label">Grund</InputLabel>
                <Select
                  labelId="demo-customized-select-label"
                  id="demo-customized-select"
                  value={grund}
                  onChange={handleGrundChange}
                >
                  <MenuItem value={10}>Ausgabe</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value={20}>MHD</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value={30}>Zu viel Produziert</MenuItem>
                </Select>
              </FormControl>
            </Grid>

            <FormControl required className={classes.formControl}>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                  <DatePicker
                    label="Datum"
                    value={datum}
                    format="dd/MM/yyyy"
                    onChange={handleDatumChange}
                    animateYearScrolling
                  />
                </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
              </Grid>
            </FormControl>
          </Grid>


          <Button
            // type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            preventDefault
            className={classes.submit}
            onClick={handleSubmit}
          >
            Save
          </Button>

          <Grid container justify="center">
            <Grid item>
              <Link to="/view">View Speisereste Records</Link>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>

          <Grid container justify="center">
            <Grid item>
              <Link to="/help">View Help</Link>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>

          <Typography style={{ margin: 7 }} variant="body1">
            Status: {message}
          </Typography>
        </FormControl>
      </div>
    </Container>

  );
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyhNe.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/In2rQ.png)

Comment: Sorry it's not working. I only want the date not the time when I post to the database,